# Check a PowerShell script line against a txt file containing computer names

Tags: powershell

I need to check the following code against a txt file with computer names, so if the computer name exist in the file, it'll be copied to the shadow group.

```
$OU="OU=Computers,DC=mylab,DC=local"
$ShadowGroup="CN=SelectPCs,OU=Groups,DC=mylab,DC=local"
Get-ADComputer –SearchBase $OU –SearchScope OneLevel –LDAPFilter "(!memberOf=$ShadowGroup)" | ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $ShadowGroup}
```

I tried a pipe and 'Where', but couldn't make it work:

```
$OU="OU=Computers,DC=mylab,DC=local"
$ShadowGroup="CN=SelectPCs,OU=Groups,DC=mylab,DC=local"
$PCList = c:\scripts\computernames.txt
Get-ADComputer –SearchBase $OU –SearchScope OneLevel –LDAPFilter "(!memberOf=$ShadowGroup)" **| Where-Object {$_.Name –Match $PCList}** |ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $ShadowGroup}
```

Comment: What's the specific error or misbehaviour you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rewrite your command as follows:

```
Get-Content c:\scripts\computernames.txt | Get-ADComputer -Property MemberOf | 
   Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -match ('^[^,]+,' + $OU + '$') -and 
                  $_.MemberOf -notcontains $ShadowGroup } |         
    ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $ShadowGroup}
```

- Start with your list of computer names, which `Get-ADComputer` should be able to identify directly, via the pipeline, implicitly bound to the `-Identity` parameter.
- `-Property MemberOf` ensures that the non-default property `MemberOf` is included in each return object.
- The `Where-Object` call then checks whether the computer is in the right OU (`$_.DistinguishedName -match ('^[^,]+,' + $OU + '$')` - *perhaps you don't even need this, given that you've identified the computers by name*<sup>[1]</sup>
  ) and whether it's not already a member of `$ShadowGroup` (`$_.MemberOf -notcontains $ShadowGroup`).
- Finally, the `Foreach-Object` calls adds the matching computers to group `$ShadowGroup`.

---

<sup>[1] Computers are assumed to have unique names, so using `Get-ADComputer` with a computer *name* (which implies parameter `-Identity`) matches a computer in *any* OU, so there's *generally* no need to constrain the matches by OU.

That said, the regex used above is explicitly designed to only match computers located *directly* in `$OU`.

If you wanted to match computers in the specified OU *and any descendent OU*, use `$_.DistinguishedName -match (',' + $OU + '$')`</sup>

Comment: This one worked just fine. Thanks mklement0! You saved me a lot of time this weekend!

Comment: Done! What's the wild card to be added to Where-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -match ('^[^,]+,' + $OU) so it'll search sub OUs as well?

Comment: @RayDar: I don't think you actually need that, because using `Get-ADComputer` with a computer SAM account name (parameter `-Identity`) finds the computer in _any_ OU.

Comment: It's not doing it for me. Looks like `{ $_.DistinguishedName -match ('^[^,]+,' + $OU)` is narrowing the results from Get-ADComputer to only the ones that their Dist.Name is matching the $OU. Since all sub OUs will have the same postfix on their Dist.Name, I thought something like *$OU (meaning `anything+OU=test,DC=mylab,DC=local`) should do the trick, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @RayDar: See if the footnote I've added helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to match a name with the array of computer names. That would be like asking does 'computer1' contain 'computer1, computer2, computer3' which would be false. But asking if 'computer1, computer2, computer3' contains the string 'computer1' would be true.

In other words, instead of `Where-Object {$_.Name -match $PCList}` you could do `Where-Object {$PCList -match $_.Name}`.

Keep in mind though that this would also do partial matches. For example computer1 would match for computer1 and also computer11, computer12, etc.

The better approach would be to loop through the list of computernames in the text file to perform your check and action (as mklement0's answer demonstrates).

Comment: Good analysis, though `$PCList` isn't even an array, it's a string, so you'd have to use `(Get-Content $PCList)`. Also, the better operator to use is probably `-eq`, because `-match` will match substrings. Finally, given that we have a list of computers as input, it's probably easier to feed them to `Get-ADComputer` for direct identification to start with only the candidate computers (which is what my answer does).

Comment: Good point. I missed that he was just declaring $PCList as the path to the file and never actually got its contents with Get-Content. I agree that I would do it much like your answer shows where you loop through the list of computer names from the file.